# Converting strings to Map in java

Tags: java, json, dictionary

How should I convert `{A=1,B=2,C=3}` into map type object like `{'A':"1",'B':"2",'C':"3"}` in java ?Is there any existing API to do this?

Comment: what is `{A=1,B=2,C=3}`?

Comment: @wero  In JSON format , it is the value parameter of {key:value} pair. Example: {'IdNo.' : "{A=1, B=2, C=3}"}, IdNo. is the key and {A=1, B=2, C=3} is the value. I want to convert the value field to map so that I can access the the value of A, B and C.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `split()` and do something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "{A=1,B=2,C=3}";
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(String str : input.substring(1,input.length() - 1).split(",")) {
        String[] data = str.split("=");
        map.put(data[0],Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Output:

```
{A=1, B=2, C=3}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear solution. The Map should be of type <String,Integer> or <String,Object> and it shouldn't throw Exception. Right ?

Comment: @Ashley I have changed the map from `<String, String>` to `<String, Integer>` in the code. It can throw `NumberFormatException` if it is unable to parse the input. Please check the updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = 
  Arrays.stream(str.replaceAll("^.|.$", "").split(","))
  .map(s -> s.split("="))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> new Integer(a[1])));
```

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

This first trims the first and last chars, then splits on comma, then splits again on equals sign, then collects to a map. Voila.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are pretty good for capturing text from a well formatted string. Something like the following:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
for (int g = 1; g < matcher.groupCount(); g += 2) {
    map.put(matcher.group(g), Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(g+1)));
}
```